# Collect items in order in game (Corona SDK)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am creating a game, and in it the player has to collect coins to gain a bigger score. There are 3 coins and when you collect one, it displays on the "coin bar" in the UI.  There are 3 empty holes for the coins (like in Cut the Rope and other games).  Currently, when the player collects the second coin, the second hole in the bar is filled.  I want the holes to be filled sequentially, so that collecting the second coin having not collected the first will fill the first hole.

Here is the code:

> ------Coin Bar
>
> ```
>     local coin_bar = {}
>     for i=1,3 do
>         coin_bar[i] = display.newImage ("coin_bar.png", 57, 57)
>     end
>
>     coin_bar[1].x = 325 
>     coin_bar[1].y = 37
>     coin_bar[2].x = 385 
>     coin_bar[2].y = 37
>     coin_bar[3].x = 445 
>     coin_bar[3].y = 37
> ```
>
> --add coins and handling
>
> ```
>     local coinSprites=grabber.grabSheet("starAnim")
>     local coinGroup = display.newGroup()
>     local coins = {}
>     isLiving = {}
>     for i=1,3 do
>         isLiving[i] = 1
>         coins[i] = coinSprites:grabSprite("",true,{ starAnim={1,6,200,0}})
>         coins[i]:playClip("starAnim")
>         coinGroup:insert(coins[i])
>     end
>
>     local function coinCollect(event)
>         for i=1, 3 do -- Nr of Coins
>             coin_clear = false
>             if isLiving[i] == 1 then
>                 if ball.x > coins[i].x -40 and ball.x < coins[i].x +40
>                 and  ball.y > coins[i].y -40 and ball.y < coins[i].y +40 then
>                 coins[i]:removeSelf()
>                 coins[i] = nil
>                 coins[i] = display.newImage ("coin_bar_collected.png", 57, 57)
>                 coins[i].x = coin_bar[i].x
>                 coins[i].y = coin_bar[i].y
>                 isLiving[i] = 0
>                 end
>             end
>         end
>     end
>
>     Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", coinCollect )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing all the stuff in the coin bar with this:

```
------Coin Bar

local coin_bar = {}
for i=1,3 do
    coin_bar[i] = display.newImage ("coin_bar.png", 325+(i*60), 37)
end
```

See if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a collected property to coin bar that tracks the last used position and use that?  Ie:

```
local coin_bar = {collected = 0}

...

local function coinCollect(event)
    for i=1, 3 do -- Nr of Coins
        coin_clear = false
        if isLiving[i] == 1 then
            if ball.x > coins[i].x -40 and ball.x < coins[i].x +40
            and  ball.y > coins[i].y -40 and ball.y < coins[i].y +40 then
            coins[i]:removeSelf()
            coins[i] = nil
            coins[i] = display.newImage ("coin_bar_collected.png", 57, 57)
            local bar_index = coin_bar.collected + 1
            coins[i].x = coin_bar[bar_index].x
            coins[i].y = coin_bar[bar_index].y
            coin_bar.collected = bar_index
            isLiving[i] = 0
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: don't you mind to help me with this little thing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283740/collision-of-a-drawed-line-and-objectscorona-sdk thanks in advance!